# PHP - Validating Password with MD5 and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a registration page which hashes passwords and stores it in MySQL. I am having an issue upon login where PHP is not recognizing the username and password. I have searched for answers, and tried to implement the many examples but none have worked. Below is the code:

```
?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['insert'])){
    // username and password sent from form

    $hostname = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "Passw0rk1";
    $databaseName = "change_management";

     $connect = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $databaseName);

     $user = $_POST['user'];
     $passcode = $_POST['passcode'];


     $sql = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username = '$user' and passcode ='".md5($passcode)."'";
     $result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
     $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

     $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

     // If result match $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

     if($count ==0) {
        echo "Invalid Credentials";
        }else {
```

I know the credentials I am inputting are present in the SQL but I am getting 'Invalid Credentials' echoed on the screen.

Here is the registration page incase there is an issue here:

```
?php 
if(isset($_POST['insert']))
{


    $hostname = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "Passw0rk1";
    $databaseName = "change_management";


    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $passcode = $_POST['passcode'];

     $connect = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $databaseName);

     $sql = "INSERT INTO `admin` (`username`, `passcode`) VALUES('$user', '".md5('$passcode')."')";

     $result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);

    if($result)
    {
     echo "Added successfully"; 
    }

    else{
        echo $connect->error;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: ***You really shouldn't use [MD5 password hashes](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure)*** and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. Make sure  you [don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe! [Don't believe it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38297105/1011527)

Comment: If you used PHP's methods and prepared statements (both mentioned above) you would never have to worry about these simple typos.

Comment: Great moment to learn debugging with var_dump..   `$sql = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username = '$user' and passcode ='".md5($passcode)."'"; var_dump($sql);`... en copy paste SQL in your database administration program like PHPMyAdmin/SQLyog and see if you get any records or a error

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Please post the markup for the form you're submitting to run this script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Your code is not secure consider using php's [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) function and [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)!

Maybe change this line.

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username = '$user' and passcode ='".md5('passcode')."'";
```

To

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username = '" . $user . "' and passcode ='".md5($passcode)."'";
```

In your registration page the line

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO `admin` (`username`, `passcode`) VALUES('$user', '".md5('$passcode')."')";
```

Should be

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO `admin` (`username`, `passcode`) VALUES('" . $user . "', '".md5($passcode)."')";
```

But the md5 is not secure and you should consider using password_hash as said in a comment.

Comment: still the same result. 'Invalid Credentials'. @DB93

Comment: Then the username and password combination is invalid and no row is returned from the database.

Comment: I changed the to query so it is now adding the user variable but be careful the user variable is not escaped and could make sql injections happen.

Comment: again, still the same result. cant help but feel like its something so simple we are all overlooking it

Comment: @S.King can check your credentials!!

Comment: ive spent 3 hours checking them, I am pretty sure they are correct

Comment: @S.King Update your insert query I the post answer

Comment: @DB93 FIXED! Problem was with the register page. Needed a gifted pair of fresh eyes! Thank you for your help mate, big thumbs up!

Answer (score 2):

change

```
md5('passcode')
```

to

```
md5($passcode)
```

Comment: still the same result, 'Invalid Credentials' @Danyal Sandeelo

Comment: how do you save the password? you are using md5 of mysql right?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the proper method to deal with passwords using MySQLi, prepared statements and PHP's password methods ***(You must store the password in the database with `password_hash()` - [read more here](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html))***:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['insert'])){
    // username and password sent from form

    $hostname = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "Passw0rk1";
    $databaseName = "change_management";

    $connect = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $databaseName);

    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $passcode = $_POST['passcode'];

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($connect, "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $user); // bind parameters
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt); //execute query
    $result = $stmt->get_result(); // get result
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc(); // put results into array

   if (password_verify($passcode, $row['passcode'])) {
       echo 'Password is valid!';
   } else {
       echo 'Invalid password.';
   }
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt); // close statement
}
```

Some things to note here:

- you only have to select the row using the user name, no need to select the passcode
- you do not have to count the rows, there should only be one row with that username
- you may want to test if the query was successful (I skipped that here)
- you will want to make sure you're properly checking for database errors like connection and query success, I've omitted that here.
- Please read [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php), and [MD5 is not secure](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure)

---

For your insert you should do this:

```
$user = $_POST['user'];
$passcode = password_hash($_POST['passcode'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

$connect = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $databaseName);

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($connect,"INSERT INTO `admin` (`username`, `passcode`) VALUES(?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $user, $passcode);
```

Then you can execute and check the insertion.